# Некорректно отображаются иконки Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, javascript, html, css, icon

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons некорректно отображаются на хостинге, на локальном сервере всё ок, в чём дело?

локальный сервер http://prntscr.com/259qmi
хостинг http://prntscr.com/259qtq

Comment: продебаж инспектором кода и посмотри подтягиваются ли картики, верно ли пути указаны

Comment: я так понял, что это не иконки а символы вот что сказал firebug на локальном сервере 
.glyphicon-plus-sign:before {
    content: "";
}

а вот что на хостинге

.glyphicon-plus-sign:before {
    content: "";
}

Comment: ну как бы и там и там одинаково показывает)

Comment: Хз ничего не понимаю

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте пути подключения иконочного шрифта в @font-face, скорее всего проблема в этом.

Comment: может в кодировке дело?

Comment: @NoName, вместо кириллицы китаица? =)

Answer (score 0):

класс пиши не так:
<i class="glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>

а вот так:
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>